# Ignore hidden rows in Loop VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I have this code that get stock prices. All stock symbols are in a table list, now if the symbol is not in watchlist, its row will be hidden. My challenge now or what I want to achieve is to ignore these hidden rows from getting its stock price. I just want it be simply ignored by the code.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Current result is this (those that are "No" in watchlist are hidden rows, but the code still return its price):

Rows  Symbol     Price    Watchlist(Filter)

1      ABS         17         Yes

2      BDO         **19**         No

3      NIKL        4          Yes

4      TECH        **5**          No

5      MWC         10         Yes

What I want to achieve is for the code to just ignore those stocks/rows that are hidden from getting the stock price.

Rows  Symbol     Price    Watchlist(Filter)

1      ABS         17         Yes

2      BDO                 No

3      NIKL        4          Yes

4      TECH                  No

5      MWC         10         Yes

```
'Last row find
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("A6:A" & lastrow)

'Clear Prior Prices
ws.Range("H6:I" & lastrow).ClearContents

n = 6
'Get Symbols list

For Each x In rng

symbol = x


Set myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myrequest.Open "Get", "http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/" & symbol & ".json"
On Error Resume Next
myrequest.Send


If myrequest.ResponseText = "" Then

 i = 0
 ws.Range(Cells(n, 8), Cells(n, 8)) = i
 ws.Range(Cells(n, 9), Cells(n, 9)) = i


 Else

  Dim Json As Object
  Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)
    i = Json("stock")(1)("price")("amount")
    ws.Range(Cells(n, 8), Cells(n, 8)) = i
    i = Json("stock")(1)("percent_change") / 100
     ws.Range(Cells(n, 9), Cells(n, 9)) = i


 End If

n = n + 1

Next x
```

Comment: `If x.entirerow.Hidden = false then`

Comment: Hi Scott, may I know where exactly I should put the suggested code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below.

```
'Last row find
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("A6:A" & lastrow)

'Clear Prior Prices
ws.Range("H6:I" & lastrow).ClearContents

n = 6
'Get Symbols list

For Each x In rng

If x.entirerow.Hidden = false then
symbol = x

Set myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myrequest.Open "Get", "http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/" & symbol & ".json"
On Error Resume Next
myrequest.Send


If myrequest.ResponseText = "" Then  
 i = 0
 ws.Range(Cells(n, 8), Cells(n, 8)) = i
 ws.Range(Cells(n, 9), Cells(n, 9)) = i

 Else

  Dim Json As Object
  Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)
    i = Json("stock")(1)("price")("amount")
    ws.Range(Cells(n, 8), Cells(n, 8)) = i
    i = Json("stock")(1)("percent_change") / 100
     ws.Range(Cells(n, 9), Cells(n, 9)) = i
 End If  
End if
n = n + 1

Next x
```